# Using regex to extract product name from URL with Google BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract the product names from the URLs below using regex in Google BigQuery:

`https://www.example.com/en/uk/product/clothing/trousers-leggings/cool-grey-joggers-9800977`

Product name should be: `cool-grey-joggers`

`https://www.example.com/en/uk/product/hot-denim-dress-7842666`

Product name should be: `hot-denim-dress`

I have tried the following regular expression:

```
'/product/(.+)-[0-9]+$'
```

but this seems to be greedy matching and will return:

`clothing/trousers-leggings/cool-grey-joggers`

`hot-denim-dress`

I have tried numerous variations of the above but all are either not matching anything or capturing too much.

How can I modify so it captures the product name only and not the the parent sub folders as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/product/` has to be part of the path:

```
/product/(?:[^/]+/)*([^/]+)-[0-9]+$
```

The pattern matches:

- `/product/` Match literally
- `(?:[^/]+/)*` Optionally repeat matching parts that end with a `/`
- `([^/]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ occurrence of any char except `/`
- `-[0-9]+$` Match `-` and 1+ digits till the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ci0pHB/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('https://www.example.com/en/uk/product/clothing/trousers-leggings/cool-grey-joggers-9800977', r'([^/]+)-[0-9]+$')
UNION ALL
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('https://www.example.com/en/uk/product/hot-denim-dress-7842666', r'([^/]+)-[0-9]+$')
```

[image]